# Standard deviation of two items

Tags: standard-deviation

I am doing an experiment and I measured 2 quantities (X and Y). From the samples of each quantity I calculated the uncertainty (standard deviation).

I need to know the uncertainty of `X/Y`. What should I do?

Comment: Compute $Z={X \over Y}$ and then compute the standard deviation of $Z$.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But doesn't dividing order of samples matter? For example consider 3 samples. Then, `X1/Y1, X2/Y2, X3/Y3` will give a different uncertainty when compared to `X3/Y1, X2/Y2, X1/Y3`. isn't it?

Comment: Of course. Given samples $(x_k,y_k)$, compute $z_k = {x_k \over y_k}$, in context, it makes no sense to compute ${x_i \over y_j}$ from different samples. The notation $Z={X \over Y}$ means $z_k = {x_k \over y_k}$ in this case.

Comment: Hey. Sorry I am a noob in this. Could you please explain me with an example? One more thing, X and Y are measured at two different time, so they are independent.

Comment: You collected samples $(x_k,y_k)$. Now compute the measurement $z_k = {x_k \over y_k}$. Now compute the standard deviation of $z_k$.